# Why has my question been put "On Hold"?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, close-reasons, review

I have a question about my Physics Stack Exchange post: [Could you help me please with mathematical model of the soil freezing process?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363483/)

I got it (I fix my question)

Why is it "On Hold"?

Comment: You edited your question **20 minutes ago**. Regardless of whether your edits fixed what was wrong with the question, you should never expect any sort of response in that short a time span.

Comment: [Review ticket for the question at hand](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/192704).

Comment: Frankly, I voted to remain closed because you have dumped an equation on us, said you were using it to model something, and then asked us to explain to you what you are modeling. The onus is on you to actually try and figure out the physics of the problem, and ask more directed questions when you run into a dead end.

Comment: @ACuriousMind That sounds like it should be an answer

Comment: @JonCuster That also sounds like it should be an answer

Answer (score 3):

I voted to keep the question closed for similar reasons as what Emilio wrote in a comment to the question: you have a wildly specific equation that must have come from somewhere, didn't they explain what it is and how it's derived?

So while it doesn't seem to be *too broad*, as was originally closed, it's not clear what research of your own you've done to address the issue. Hence, I voted to keep it closed.

If you **provided the resource** that gave you the equation ***and* some relevant text *around* the given equation** in that resource, it might be easier for *us* to understand what is missing and, thus, reopen the question.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to point out what they disagree with?

Comment: I agree completely. Plus, without the OP actually understanding the physics of the equation there is no hope of actually getting anything useful out of the simulations.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226696141_Numerical_simulation_of_coupled_heat-fluid_transport_in_freezing_soils_using_finite_volume_method

Comment: @sasvak posting link the here will do you little good, you need to edit your post with the details (**not** just the link)